# How to consume blob file?

Tags: python, excel, google-cloud-storage, blob

I am having an issue, I am uploading xlsx files to google storage.
When I want to reuse them later on I obtain a blob file.

After that I am loss on how to use the actual xlsx file.

```
from google.cloud import storage

import openpyxl

client = storage.Client()
new_bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket.appspot.com')

#get blob object:
o = new_bucket.get_blob('old_version.xlsx')

# <Blob: blobstorage.appspot.com, old_version.xlsx, 16372393787851916>

#download the object

bytes_version = o.download_as_bytes()

#load it to openpyxl library
wb = load_workbook(filename = bytes_version ,data_only=True)

InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support b'.xmlpk\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00:\x00:\x00n\x10\x00\x00\xa6\x06\x01\x00\x00\x00' file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

End goal would be to download the file as object and read them with openpyxl library (it work with the original file but after the storage on cloud didn't find way to get my xlsx file).

Thank for the help !

edit: adding current code

Comment: Either method will work. What is the problem that you are having after you download the object?

Comment: Can you also provide the piece of code?

Comment: Google search. There are many examples in Python using those methods. The missing item in your question is **what problem are you having**?

Comment: Edit added with the code used, current issue is the error due to the file not being the original but the blob or transformed version of the file and the openpyxl library do not recognize the original file as xlsx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is reading the Cloud Storage blob into memory:

```
bytes_version = o.download_as_bytes()
```

And then trying to load the workbook from memory:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = bytes_version ,data_only=True)
```

However, the **load_workbook()** method expects a filename or a file-like object. **Using a byte string with the file contents is not supported**.

> openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename, read_only=False,
> keep_vba=False, data_only=False, keep_links=True)
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> filename (string or a file-like object open in binary mode c.f., zipfile.ZipFile) – the path to open or a file-like object
> ```

[Documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html)

**Solution:**

Save the Cloud Storage blob to a local disk file first and then specify the file name in the call to **load_workbook()**:

```
o.download_to_filename('/path/to/file')
wb = load_workbook(filename = '/path/to/file' ,data_only=True)
```

Note: Replace **/path/to/file** with a real path on your system and with the **.xlsx** file extension.

Comment: Thank you John, understood the issue I though It would be possible to load the file from memory in that case definitly wrong. Thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as (assuming Python3):

```
import io  # Python3
wb = load_workbook(io.BytesIO(bytes_version))
```

Comment: this worked for me when i was trying to extract the Excel blob from a PowerPoint file.